# What's the word for 'new yet old'?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives

I am trying to think of the word that describes something that is new yet old, contemporary yet classic, progressive yet traditional or any other similar meanings.

The word is used to describe a synthesis of two opposing meanings. Eg. That dress is fashionable yet is also a classic.

I read the post that used the word shibui to describe something that is simple but also very complex.

In essence, I am looking for the word that describes something that is contemporary but also timeless.

Comment: Oxymoronic? This refers to the combination of two (seemingly) opposing elements, e.g. Cold fire, Deafening silence, etc.

Comment: Please see the checklist at the end of the [single-word-request tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and include details of how your word is to be used -- a sentence which shows context with a blank for the word would be a good start; but do give as much detail as possible.

Comment: If this were still open I'd suggest **retro** which refers to the modern expression of an otherwise outdated fashion or concept.

Comment: @Jim Mack You just did.

Comment: @Huey Sometimes, people try to be too clever and end up instead with a contradiction in terms: the attempted combination of two mutually exclusive elements.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but I did not find the word I was looking for. The word is not explaining a contradiction but rather a unification of two opposing elements. Eg. That dress is so fashionable yet a classic. Or something along those lines. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

Depending on context:

***alive***

> alive
>
> adjective
>
> 2 a :  still in existence, force, or operation :  effective at least
>   to a degree :  not dead, defunct, or extinct :  existent, active
>
> b :  still in use :  current to a degree :  still exerting force or
>   influence
>
> c *bowls* :  in play :  not dead
>
> d :  still active in competition with a chance of victory
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary